# How to send an auto reply email with a html page as email in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, html-email

I recently started programming in NodeJS. I can't find any way how can I send an auto-reply email. When another person sends me an email, in that time an auto-reply email will be sent to his/her email, which is in HTML email format.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to poll or monitor your account for the incoming mail, using a generic `smtp or imap client`, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap, or even better, a module that actually monitors new email, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-notifier

The posted example is

```js
Start listening new mails :

const notifier = require('mail-notifier');
 
const imap = {
  user: "yourimapuser",
  password: "yourimappassword",
  host: "imap.host.com",
  port: 993, // imap port
  tls: true,// use secure connection
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
};
 
notifier(imap)
  .on('mail', mail => console.log(mail))
  .start();
Keep it running forever :

const n = notifier(imap);
n.on('end', () => n.start()) // session closed
  .on('mail', mail => console.log(mail.from[0].address, mail.subject))
  .start();
```

Next, its hard to beat `nodemailer` to send your response.

https://nodemailer.com/about/

Here is their example. (Half this code is comments and logs)

```js
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {
  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
  let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
    },
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: "bar@example.com, baz@example.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
}

main().catch(console.error);
```